# How to improve running time of nested for loops when appending a dataframe (very large)

Tags: python, performance, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I am reading in a 4-dimensional netcdf file and iterating through each variable and appending them to a pandas DataFrame. The number of iterations for each level, from outer to inner, is: 40, 90, 144, 312. In the inner loop I am appending all 312 values into an array, where I then set this array to the corresponding cell in the dataframe. It has currently been running for ~1 hour, and it has only gone through half of the first pass of the outer loop (I am using print statements to indicate how far into the iteration it is). Using this time, I estimated that it will take around 2 hours to complete the first pass of the outer loop, and there are 40 outer loops, therefore the program should terminate in 80 hours. This is extremely long, and I have to do this entire process for multiple datasets! This dataset is 161,740,800 values. How can I speed up this process? Are there more efficient ways to create the dataframe?

I am doing this so that I can run linear regression and other ML techniques on the data. I have tried using xarray to read in the netcdf file directly, then convert it to a dask dataframe. I have been having issues accessing the data with these methods... everytime I try to do something to see the actual data, the kernel will crash, even if it is just a simple .head(1) command. (I am using Python2.7 and Spyder). I am trying to write a repackaging program that will take the netcdf file (which is pretty confusing for me to understand and work with), and turn it into an easy to handle dataframe. I am open to trying the xarray or dask dataframe again, but I'm not sure how to deal with the kernel crashing within seconds of running a .head() or .tail() operation (let alone the linear regression/random forest!). Please advise! The data is atmospheric data.

```py
def __init__(self):

        self.data = xr.open_dataset('/Users/Desktop/Data/O3_vmr_MON_1861-1886.S1anl_1c6_1870.nc')

        self.lon = self.data.variables['lon'] # longitude
        self.lat = self.data.variables['lat'] # latitude
        self.level = self.data.variables['level'] # level/height
        self.plm = self.data.variables['plm'] 
        self.ple = self.data.variables['ple']
        self.O3 = self.data.variables['O3_vmr'] # ozone


    def loop(self):

        ozone_arr = [] # array to hold all the values at each level,lat,lon point in time
        ozone_df = [] 

        # for loop to go through all values over time
        for lev in range(0,40):
            for lat in range(0,90):
                for lon in range(0,144): 
                    for t in range(0,312):
                        ozone_arr.append(self.data.O3_vmr[t,lev,lat,lon].values)

                    ozone_df.append({'level':self.level[lev].values, 'lat':self.lat[lat].values, 'lon':self.lon[lon].values, 'O3': ozone_arr})
                    ozone_arr = [] # reset array of all values at this point in time

                print('lat', lat) # to monitor progress
            print('lev', lev) # to monitor progress

        ozone_df = pd.DataFrame(ozone_df)
        print(ozone_df.head(100))

        self.ozone_df = ozone_df
```

Trying to record all O3 (ozone) measurements over time for each combination of level, lat, and lon.

Comment: If you know the length of the arrays, you might be able to save a bit of time by pre-allocating (or, similarly, rewriting this as a list comprehension).

Comment: Otherwise, I would stay away from spyder for this sort of thing -- I've had issues with memory leaks in their console before and I wouldn't be surprised if that has something to do with the crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try reshaping the data to 2 dimensions first using [np.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

```
import numpy as np

ozone_arr = np.reshape(data, (length_of_df, num_columns))
```

Then insert into a DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ozone_arr)
```

This approach is much faster because your data shape will change without having to move around in memory.

Depending on how your data is structured, you may have to slice it in order to get it into the shape you need.  You may want to practice with a small array to figure out how NumPy works.

Most importantly, if speed is important, avoid loops.

[NumPy slicing documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)